# textField Input String convert into UINT32

Tags: ios, string, uitextfield, textfield, uint32

need a little bit help.
How I could save a Number from a textfield into a NSInteger variable?

I got this propertys:

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldPort;
@property NSInteger *portTemp;
```

And I want something like this:

```
_portTemp = _textFieldPort.text;
```

I need the variable to pass through

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)address, port, NULL, &writeStream);
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's really easy to do that mate, try this*

```
_portTemp = [_textFieldPort.text integerValue];
```

Comment: Tank you. With this i could compile but get an warning: "Incombatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to "NSInteger*"(aka int) from 'int'

Comment: Tank you. That was the problem ;-)